# Expand collapse list item using angular material

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Can anyone give any suggestions for adding an Expand/Collapse view shown [here](https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists-controls.html#lists-controls-types-of-list-controls).
I'd like to use Angular material with AngularJS only and not be dependant on Bootstrap etc however I can't find anything suitable in the AngularMaterial docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

One way is to use 2 consecutive `md-list-item`.

Here is the HTML Code.

```
  <md-list flex>
   <md-list-item ng-click="toggle.list1 = !toggle.list1">
    <md-icon>explore</md-icon>
    <span flex>Item List 1</span>
    <md-icon ng-show="!toggle.list1">expand_more</md-icon>
    <md-icon ng-show="toggle.list1">expand_less</md-icon>
   </md-list-item>
   <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in data" ng-show="toggle.list1">
   <span flex-offset="5">{{item}}</span>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list-item ng-click="toggle.list2 = !toggle.list2">
   <md-icon>explore</md-icon>
   <span flex>Item List 2</span>
   <md-icon ng-show="!toggle.list2">expand_more</md-icon>
   <md-icon ng-show="toggle.list2">expand_less</md-icon>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in data" ng-show="toggle.list2">
   <span flex-offset="5">{{item}}</span>
  </md-list-item>
 </md-list>
```

JS Code:

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngMaterial'])
.controller('TempController', function($scope){
 $scope.data = [ "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]
 $scope.toggle = {};
});;
```

Here is the working [Codepen](http://codepen.io/next1/pen/VPoqRM).

Comment: To animate the Expand/Collapse transition, you may consider using [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations). It's really simple as adding a `section-show-hide` class to the hidden element, and this css code:

`.section-show-hide {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  max-height: 500px;
}
.section-show-hide.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
}`

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to use bootstrap.

https://github.com/LukaszWatroba/v-accordion

this should be possible code to make your own accordion with material

http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/02/accordion-with-angularjs-material-ui.html#.WKxqI1UrJaQ

Comment: Do you know if there's and example that uses just AngularMaterial? I'm not able to add extra libraries at this stage.

Comment: yeah, thats right. its not done with material. Is this one more helpful? http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/02/accordion-with-angularjs-material-ui.html#.WKxqI1UrJaQ